# dynamically append N-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, concatenation

If each array has the shape (1000, 2, 100), it is easy to use

```
con = np.concatenate((array_A, array_B))
```

to concatenate them, thus con has the shape (2000, 2, 100).

I want to dynamically append or concatenate "con" in a function. The step is described as following:

```
First, read data from the first file and process data to generate an array.

Secondly, read date from the second file and append generated array into the first array

....

def arrayappend():
     for i in range(n):
         #read data from file_0 to file_n-1
         data = read(file_i)
         #data processing to generate an array with shape (1000, 2, 100)
         con = function(data)
         # append con
```

Comment: Why can't you do the processing, append the processed data to a normal python list, then finally once the loop is done call np.concatenate() on that list?

Comment: @SilverSlash, Yes, I was think of that solution. But is there a good way to append the array each time after I process one file?

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. Why not `con = np.concatenate((con, data))` after `# append con`

Comment: @Balzola, data is the raw data, like strings in each file, con is generated or converted from data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your files produce the same shape objects and you want to join them on the 1st dimension, there are several options:

```
 alist = []
 for f in files:
    data = foo(f)
    alist.append(f)
 arr = np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)
```

`concatenate` takes a list.  There are variations if you want to add a new axis (`np.array(alist)`, `np.stack` etc).

Append to a list is fast, since it just means adding a pointer to the `data` object.  `concatenate` creates a new array from the components; it's compiled but still relatively slower.

If you must/want to make a new array at each stage you could write:

```
 arr = function(files[0])
 for f in files[1:]:
     data = foo(f)
     arr = np.concatenate((arr, data), axis=0)
```

This probably is slower, though, if the file loading step is slow enough you might not notice a difference.

With care you might be able start with `arr = np.zeros((0,2,100))` and read all files in the loop.  You have to make sure the initial 'empty' array has a compatible shape.  New users often have problems with this.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first method and it worked. So the basic idea is to append them into a list and then concatenate the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to do it during iteration then:

```
def arrayappend():
  con = None
  for i, d in enumerate(files_list):
    data = function(d)
    con = data if i is 0 else np.vstack([con, data])
```

This should stack it vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Very non pretty, but does it achieve what you want? It is way unoptimized.

```
def arrayappend():
    for i in range(n):
        data = read(file_i)
        try:
            con
            con = np.concatenate((con, function(data)))
        except NameError:
            con = function(data)
    return con
```

First loop will take the except branch, subsequent wont.