# numpy append slices to two dimensional array to make it three dimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, append

I have `5` numpy arrays with `shape (5,5)`. What I want to achieve is to combine these `5` numpy arrays to one array of shape (5,5,5). My code looks like the following but does not work:

```
combined = np.empty((0, 5, 5), dtype=np.uint8)

for idx in range(0, 5):
    array = getarray(idx) # returns an array of shape (5,5)
    np.append(combined, img, axis=0)
```

I thought if I set the first axis to 0 it will append on this axis so that in the end the shape will be (5,5,5). What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out by myself:

```
combined = np.empty((0, 5, 5), dtype=np.uint8)

for idx in range(0, 5):
    array = getarray(idx) # returns an array of shape (5,5)
    array array[np.newaxis, :, :]
    combined = np.append(combined, img, axis=0)
print combined.shape + returns (5,5,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try:

```
A = np.array([getarray(idx) for idx in range(5)])
```

Or

```
alist = []
for idx in range(5):
   alist.append(getarray(idx))
A = np.array(alist)
```

Appending to a list is faster than appending to an array.  The latter makes a totally new array - as you discovered.

[dynamically append N-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634855/dynamically-append-n-dimensional-array) - same issue, starting with different dimensions.

Comment: I have already answered my question. But thank you. Why did you bring up another answer? Do you think it is better?

Comment: Yes, I think it is faster.  You can stick with your `np.append`, but look at its code so you understand what it is doing.  And try some simple time tests.  Building arrays incrementally is a frequent SO question.

Comment: Yeah I do not need speed. I just need to get it done. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you mind editing my answer and add your code to it? Then I will accept it. Because both of them are correct I think.